# How to fix CORS Node.js on Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, angular, google-app-engine, cors

I have 2 applications deployed on Google App Engine;

A is a Angular 8 application.

B is a Node.js express application.

Whenever I try to call an API in my backend I receive this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at '"APPLICATION B"/getGroups?userKey=' from origin 'APPLICATION A' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I made sure to enable APPLICATION A url in google app engine credentials of APPLICATION B as an Authorized Javascript Origin and Authorized Redirect URI.
In localhost everything works.

What I tried on App.js:

ATTEMPT 1

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
res.header(“Access-Control-Allow-Origin”, “*”);
res.header(“Access-Control-Allow-Methods”, “GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT”);
res.header(“Access-Control-Allow-Headers”, “Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, x-client-key, x-client-token, x-client-secret, Authorization”);
next();
});
```

ATTEMPT 2

```
var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
```

ATTEMPT 3

```
var cors = require('cors')

var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'APPLICATION A',
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions ));
app.options('*', cors());
```

This is the GET I do in my angular 8 application A

```
  getGroupsRequest(id): Observable<any> {
    const url = "APPLICATION B"
    return this.http.get(url + id);
  }
```

If I use a CORS plugin or open google chrome "--disable-web-security" it works.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir="C:\Users\510919\ChromeDev" --disable-web-security --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your app.js in your Node.js file

```
var express = require('express')
  ,cors = require('cors')
  , app = express();

var originsWhitelist = [
  '<FRONT-END URL>',     
   'http://www.myproductionurl.com'
];
var corsOptions = {
  origin: function(origin, callback){
        var isWhitelisted = originsWhitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1;
        callback(null, isWhitelisted);
  },
  credentials:true
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

This will enable on your Node.js

Now you will need to prepare your Angular app to support CORS

To enable CORS you can extend the `BrowserXhr` and include that in the bootstrapping process. Create a file in your Angular application project named `cust-ext-browser-xhr.ts` and paste the following code:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {BrowserXhr} from "@angular/http";
@Injectable()

export class CustExtBrowserXhr extends BrowserXhr {
  constructor() {
      super();
  }
  build(): any {
    let xhr = super.build();
    xhr.withCredentials = true; 
    return <any>(xhr);
  }
}
```

And in order to use your **Custom BrowserXhr** you will need to do something like this.

```
import { provide } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent} from './app/';
import { BrowserXhr } from '@angular/http';
import {CustExtBrowserXhr} from './app/path-to-file/cust-ext-browser-xhr';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpModule,
    BrowserModule,
    …
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    {provide: BrowserXhr, useClass:CustExtBrowserXhr},
    {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
    …
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Validate that you are using your custom browserXhr, anda validate all your URL, maybe you have a typo or something