# Google Cloud node app can't connect Cross origin request blocked

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, vuejs2, cors

I've just deployed a node.js -  vue.2.0 app to Google Cloud .

The vue.js 2.0 app is inside of the public node directory . Everything runs fine, except that all my queries to the web services are failing , inside of the habitual app.js node file, you know .. There are not calls to any other node server, that is why i even have tried localhost:8080 as a server name.

https://cedar-network-259109.appspot.com

All back end queries done from the app are failing :

```
POST
http://localhost:8080/getUsers

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/getUsers. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

I've also managed the app to call the google cloud server url : same error .

```
POST http://cedar-network-259109.appspot.com:8080/getUsers
```

It doesnt work neither.

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/getUsers. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

- This app is correctly working when deployed on **openode.io** host : http://vue-starter-webpack-cli-4-node.openode.io/.
- MongoDb Atlas is connected (0.0.0.0 wildcard).

***QUESTION :***
Do I have to configure **cors** on my google cloud app with this doc , using the strange command? :

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors

Thanks a lot !

**EDIT :** This is what I got when asking about my cors config, it looks like I haven't got any cors config ? :

```
C:\UwAmp\www\vue-starter-webpack-cli-4-node-gcloud>gsutil cors get gs://cedar-network-259109.appspot.com
gs://cedar-network-259109.appspot.com/ has no CORS configuration.
```

**EDIT 2 :**

I'm sending a CORS params to my google cloud app like this :

```
>gsutil cors set cors-json-file.json gs://cedar-network-259109.appspot.com
```

This is my cors-json-file.json file :

```
  [
    {
      "origin": ["https://cedar-network-259109.appspot.com"],
      "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
      "method": ["GET", "POST","HEAD", "DELETE"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    },
    {
      "origin": ["https://cedar-network-259109.appspot.com:8080"],
      "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
      "method": ["GET", "POST","HEAD", "DELETE"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]
```

There is still an error :

```
POST https://cedar-network-259109.appspot.com:8080/getUsers
    Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://cedar-network-259109.appspot.com:8080/getUsers. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

*There are my informations :*

```
>gsutil cors get  gs://cedar-network-259109.appspot.com
[{"maxAgeSeconds": 3600, "method": ["GET", "POST", "HEAD", "DELETE"], "origin": ["https://cedar-network-259109.appspot.com:8080"], "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"]}]
```

And my Request URL:https://cedar-network-259109.appspot.com:8080/getUsers headers :

```
Host: cedar-network-259109.appspot.com:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: fr,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://cedar-network-259109.appspot.com/
Origin: https://cedar-network-259109.appspot.com
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 0
```

**My app.yaml file :**

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

**EDIT 3 :** Modified my node app.js backend with this code :

```
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(
  require("cors")({
    origin: function(origin, callback) {
      callback(null, origin);
    },
    credentials: true
  })
);
```

to this :

```
app.use(
  require("cors")({
    origin: "https://cedar-network-259109.appspot.com",
    credentials: true
  })
);
```

With no luck ! **Please help me** !

Answer (score 0):

If the resources you are trying to access are stored on Google Cloud Storage then you'll need to enable CORS as explained on the [documentation you mention](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors). If the resources you are trying to access files hosted by another Google App Engine app you need to modify your app.yaml file as explained on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#handlers_http_headers).

Comment: No, the node.js backend app.js is on the same unique google app, connecting to mongodb atlas.

Comment: I would appreciate if somebody could help me. Do I have to modify app.yaml ?

Comment: If you are not trying to access the files form another Google App Engine application you don't need to modify the app.yaml file. You are  going to need to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` HTTP header within your application. If you are looking for some code samples you can check this other posts [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001817/allow-cors-rest-request-to-a-express-node-js-application-on-heroku) or [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57958849/how-to-fix-cors-node-js-on-google-app-engine).

Comment: Thanks a lot, lets try this !